# How long does it take to get into Low Earth Orbit?

Tags: launch, orbit, low-earth-orbit

I've seen varying times for spacecraft/rockets getting into LEO, e.g. according do the [Mercury-Atlas 7 Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercury-Atlas_7), it took just over 5 minutes to get into a 259x154km orbit, whereas the [Saturn V article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturn_V#S-IVB_sequence) says that it took a "typical" Saturn V launch nearly 12 minutes to get into orbit.

Comment: Around 10 minutes depending on the type of rocket, its load (manned flights tend to be slower to limit acceleration to survivable values) and the intended orbit, 5 min is extremely fast.

Comment: Hobbes is correct; 10-12 minutes is a typical time to orbit. Mercury-Atlas was an outlier as a result of its ICBM heritage; some modern launchers (e.g Ariane) use a very fuel-efficient, low-thrust upper stage which leads to a longer time to orbital insertion, up to 15-20 minutes.